# Go to character # in json file

Tags: json, swift, xcode

Every now and then, there will be a wrong character in one of the json files I work with. Xcode will give an error message like this:

*Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 17355484." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 17355484.}*

Is there a way I can jump to this character in the file inside Xcode?

Comment: Could you print your JSON? Why do you have this character? Is it a valid JSON (compared to a valid "iOS" one)? Else, you can convert your JSON as NSData to NSString, remove the char at that index and reconstruct the JSON, but finding that index is a little hacky.

Comment: @Larme In this case, the json file was created using the csvtojson website. There may be unexpected characters due to silly Excel number/date formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have the real string you could create an `NSRange` from 10 characters before that place and length 20

```
let nsRange = NSRange(location: 17355474, length: 20)
```

Then get the Swift `String.Index` range (assuming `string` is the JSON string)

```
let swiftRange = Range(nsRange, in: string)!
```

and print it

```
print(string[swiftRange])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Xcode won't even let me arrive there as it crashes when reading the file giving that error. I've tried your suggestion like that: let jsonString = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonFileAsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! NSString
 let nsRange = NSRange(location: 17355474, length: 20)
print(jsonString.substring(with: nsRange)) Could you put your solution into the context of working with a json file?

Comment: You have to create the string from data **before** calling `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`. `let string = String(data: jsonFileAsData, encoding: .utf8)` `let nsRange = ....` and comment out the rest of the scope.

Comment: Ok, that did the trick, thanks a lot. For anyone concerned, it seems you have to cast the string to NSString in order to access the .substring(with: NSRange) method.

Comment: No, you don't have to. Use the syntax `string[swiftRange]` which is the native equivalent to `substring(to`